# select radio button by index

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am using C# selenium driver in visual studio for automating my scripts.The data in my radio button gets dynamically generated and I want to select the radio button using index . These are the ways I tried

**Method 1**

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("XX"))).SelectByIndex(2);Click();
```

In first method , I am not able to relate the Click to the element

**Method 2**

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.("XX"));
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
element.Click();
```

In method 2 , I am not sure how to pass the index.

This is my HTML code :

```
<input type="radio" name="XXXX" id="XXXX" value="5273786">.
```

So These radio buttons get dynamically generated. For eg, if I have 3 radio buttons, **all 3 radio buttons have the same id and name but a different value**.

So it would be great if you could let me know **how to select the first radio button by passing its value or by selecting the radio button using index**.

Comment: Can you add in an example of the code itself please

Comment: If your element is radio button, why are you going to click using `SelectElement` while it expect element should be dropdown with `select` tag..could you share HTML of your radio button as well

Comment: Hi Saurabh, Thanks for looking into my question. I am unsure how to click the radio button. This is my HTML code <input type="radio" name="XXXX" id="XXXX" value="5273786">. So These radio buttons get dynamically generated. For eg, if I have 3 radio buttons, all 3 radio buttons have the same id and name but a different value. So it would be great if you could let me know how to select the first radio button by passing its value or by selecting the radio button using index. Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Ok..I have posted is as an answer.. try this and let me know...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try as below :-

- if you to select radio button by their value try as below using `By.XPath()` :-

  ```
  IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//input[@value = '5273786']"));
   element.Click();
  ```

  Or try as below using `By.Id()` :-

  ```
    IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("select"));
    var element = selectElements.Where(se => se.GetAttribute('value') == '5273786');
    element.Click();
  ```
- if you want to select radio button using index try as below using `By.Xpath()` :-

  ```
   IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("(//input[@id = 'XXXX'])[1]"));
   element.Click();
  ```

  Or try as below using `By.Id()` :-

  ```
  IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.Id("XXXX"));
  elements[0].Click();
  ```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: Thank you Saurabh, I tried the select radio button using index and it worked. Thanks for your help